# Differences between ChallengeHandler.submitChallengeAnswer(credentials) and WLAuthorizationManager.login(SECURITY_CHECK_NAME, credentials)

Tags: oauth-2.0, ibm-mobilefirst

What are the differences between using `ChallengeHandler.submitChallengeAnswer(credentials)` and `WLAuthorizationManager.login(SECURITY_CHECK_NAME, credentials)`?

Comment: is your doubt resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to login a user without any challenge being received. For example, showing a login screen as the first screen of the application, or showing a login screen after a logout, or a login failure. We call those scenarios preemptive logins.

You cannot call the `submitChallengeAnswer` API if there is no challenge to answer. For those scenarios, the Mobile Foundation SDK includes the login API:

```
WLAuthorizationManager.login(securityCheckName,credentials).then(
    function () {
        WL.Logger.debug("login onSuccess");
    },
    function (response) {
        WL.Logger.debug("login onFailure: " + JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

If the credentials are wrong, the security check sends back a challenge.

It is the developer’s responsibility to know when to use `login`, as opposed to `submitChallengeAnswer`, based on the application’s needs. One way to achieve this is to define a Boolean flag, for example `isChallenged`, and set it to `true` when `handleChallenge` is reached, or set it to `false` in any other cases (failure, success, initialization, etc).

When the user clicks the Login button, you can dynamically choose which API to use:

```
if (isChallenged){
    userLoginChallengeHandler.submitChallengeAnswer(credentials);
} else {
    WLAuthorizationManager.login(securityCheckName,credentials).then(
//...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MobileFirst implements OAuth 2 authorization framework, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_oauth_security_model.html. There are two stages in the implementation, Obtaining an access token, and
Accessing a protected resources by using an access token.
ChallengeHandler APIs are used to implement the first stage, Obtaining
an access token. WLAuthorizationManager APIs are used to implement the
second stage, Accessing a protected resources. More details can be found 
at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_oauth_client_apis.html?view=embed#c_oauth_client_apis